# Javascript: Cast Math.sqrt to int?

Tags: javascript, math, type-conversion, int, casting

I've searched through google (maybe I didn't look hard enough) but I could not find how to turn Math.sqrt into an int.

I want to use Math.sqrt for a *for* loop and I guess I need it as an int but I can't seem to figure out how to cast the result to an int.  So how do I do it?

I tried something similar to Java:

```
(int) Math.sqrt(num);
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `Math.round`, `Math.ceil`, or `Math.floor` depending on your specific rounding needs.

*"For rounding numbers to integers one of Math.round, Math.ceil and Math.floor are preferable, and for a desired result that can be expressed as a 32 bit signed integer the bitwise operation described below might also suit."*

-http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/type_convert.html#tcNumber

Answer (score 5):

Someone suggested parseInt. That goes from a string to an int, but it's easy to turn a float into a string.

```
parseInt(Math.sqrt(num)+"")
```

Remember that no matter what you do, JavaScript is always using floats. There is no integer type.

Comment: Edit your older question without re-posting.

Comment: Sorry. At the time I didn't seem to have the reputation to comment on the other guy's answer, which is what I was trying to do.

Comment: I think the negative vote is unwarranted considering that Nosredna didn't have the necessary rep to comment. Neutralized.

Comment: Actually the javascript number type is a double, not a float.

Comment: gs, yeah thanks. The floating point spec used by ECMASCript is IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point. I did a blog post on it once, you'd think I'd remember. http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/15/9007199254740992/

Answer (score 4):

Math.floor will do it. Doubt you even need to go to an integer, though.

```
Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `parseInt(Math.sqrt(num)+"")` is slower than using `Math.round(Math.sqrt(num))`. I think it is because in first example you are creating string, parsing integer value of `num` and rounding  it. in second example you just take int and round it.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old question, but i figure for anyone finding this later....

i won't reiterate what the other answers say, but a fun little trick you can do is:

```
Math.sqrt(2); //1.41......
~~Math.sqrt(2); //1
```

the double bitwise negative drops off anything after the decimal point.  i've been told it's slightly faster, but i'm not entirely convinced.

EDIT: as a note this will round toward 0.